# Create shared class from IHttpContextAccessor to pass it across class libraries

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, configuration

I`m using .NET Core 3.1 and I for every request I need to access some of the logged User claims and pass it to business service (another class library) outside the API project.

I`ve tried to create UserService:

```
public class UsersService
    {
       private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _context;

       public UsersService(IHttpContextAccessor context)
       {
         _context = context;
       }

    public UserSession GetUser()
    {
        return new UserSession()
        {
            UserDisplayName = _context.HttpContext.User?.Identity?.Name,

        };
    }
}
```

and in Startup.cs

```
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddHttpContextAccessor();
```

which should be used/injected by other business services or repositories like that:

```
    public class ExampleBusinessService
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _unitOfWork;
    private IUsersService _userService;
    public ExampleBusinessService(IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, IUsersService userService)
    {
        this._unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
        this._userService = userService;
    }
```

However it seems I cannot access IHttpContextAccessor outside of the Web project.
[image]

Can this be achieved?

Ofcourse I cannot create the UserService in the API and then use it in other libraries cause that mens the libraries should have reference to the web project.

If not is it possible in controller for the startup class to take the needed info from current user and pass it to the services? Or do so in the controller somehow?
As is say i need custom class with information taken from the logged user in business services (seprate class library) and repositories (seprate class library)

this is how the solution looks like i need to access the logged user info (custom UserSession class) in BusinessServices library:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: The controller class is an HTTP Server and your API (a client) would need to make a request to the server and get a response.

Comment: This whole thing is the API, just business logic is in another class library (same project)

Comment: So don't you just need a instance of the business logic in the usersession class?

Comment: Your api project should reference all other projects that it needs and the other projects can referens all others without the api and themself and at the end you can use the dependensies defined into the Startup overall where you need them. In your case it seems like you forgot to add the reference and using for IHttpContextAccessor and his dll. You may need to install the package containing the IHttpContextAccessor in your dll before using it.

Comment: @spzvtbg install Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http in the library?

Comment: @jdweng No. Business logic is a lot of services and each needs UserSession. To be like u said i need to initialize all the business services in the UserSession class. I do not think that is correct

Comment: The user class should be a sibling to the Web class.  When a user connects the Web API stores the user info into the user class.  You can make the user class static so it can be accessed without an instance both by the Web API and the Business Classes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `IHttpContextAccessor` type is part of the ASP.NET Core framework and as such only available in your web project. If you have your `UsersService` implementation in a different project, then you won’t be able to reference the context accessor correctly.

A good way to solve this is to split the contract from the implementation: Define a `IUsersService` within your library project and only reference that for your business logic. Users of the service do not need to know what things an implementation might depend on; they only care that they can use the public interface of this service.

Then in your web project, create an implementation of `IUsersService` that uses the `IHttpContextAccessor` to access the user information. Since the implementation lives within the web project, it can properly access the context accessor.

Finally, combine the interface and the implementation by registering your service implementation as part of your web application:

```cs
services.AddTransient<IUsersService, UsersService>();
```

Once your services (outside of the web project) now require the `IUsersService`, they will get the implementation that uses the context accessor to access the user information and everything should work without you having to add a reference to the ASP.NET Core framework in your (otherwise unrelated) libraries.

Comment: And this way outside library would not need reference to the web project. Very nice. Thank you!

Comment: What if we have Microservices projects, where each microservice api needs information. In the above solution, I do need to implement that UserService in each microservices api project, which is again not done right. any suggestion in the case of microservices?

Comment: @RahmanBokhari You can reuse implementations in microservices but I would argue that you probably shouldn’t need to have a *users service* in *all* your microservices.

Comment: @poke I would also argue that using a UserService is not the only use case for referencing the AspNet Core library. This was just an example. Unfortunately again on stack overflow we see alternative solutions and not an actual answer to the OP

Answer (score 3):

If you need to reference anything from the AspNet Core framework you have to options:

1. Target `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web`
2. Add an explicit `FrameworkReference` to `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App`

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <FrameworkReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
  </ItemGroup>
    ...
</Project>
```

[reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference)

Comment: Ah, the answer I was not hoping to see, I am late to the game as I see they deprecated a ton of packages and this is the way. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I understand your concern and it seems you're approaching the problem in the wrong way.
To point it out, I believe this is what you want:

- You have `ExampleBusinessService`, which resides in a shared class library
- You have `UsersService`, which deals with services of user sessions etc.
- You want to access session info through `IHttpContextAccessor`

First of all, both `ExampleBusinessService` and `UsersService` don't need to be in API project or tied to it whatsoever. You can freely put them in your class library.

Here is how you can approach this:

- Firstly, in your class library add `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` package.
- Create static class `UsersService` (in the class library)
- Add the following code (to `UsersService`)

```
public static class UsersService
{
    // extend IHttpContextAccessor 
    public static UserSession GetUserSession( this IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
         return new UserSession
         {
             UserDisplayName = _context.HttpContext.User?.Identity?.Name,
         }
    }
}
```

- Now, in your `ExampleBusinessService` inject `IHttpContextAccessor`

```
public class ExampleBusinessService
{
    private readonly IHttpContextAccessor _contextAccessor;

    public ExampleBusinessService(IHttpContextAccessor accessor)
    {
        _contextAccessor = accessor,
    }

    // now do whatever you want with the session info
    public SomeBusinessAboutSessionInfo()
    {
        // retrieve the session
        var userSession = _contextAccessor.GetUserSession();
        //...your logic
    }
}
```

The final piece (**this is important**)

- Add `IHttpContextAccessor` to your `IServiceCollection` in the API project

`services.AddTransient<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();`

**Everything should now work out!!!**

Answer (score -1):

In case of adding full dotnetcore to a shared solution (external class library project). Just add a reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.HTTP to get access to IHttpContextAccessor