# use asp.net core IHttpContextAccessor inside a core library

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-6.0

I have an ASP.NET Core 6 app, and a few routines that accept a `IHttpContextAccessor` as parameter.
I would like to move this code to a library to share among apps, but obviously the reference is missing.
Is there a way to add to resolve this interface? I think is not part of a specific package in ASP.NT Core 6, so I can't solve add a package.

Comment: I _think_ you need to add a framework reference to AspNet, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#framework-reference

Comment: You'll need a reference to the `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` NuGet package.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Create shared class from IHttpContextAccessor to pass it across class libraries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64121870/create-shared-class-from-ihttpcontextaccessor-to-pass-it-across-class-libraries)

Comment: thanks, adding  the framework solved the problem

Comment: ASP.NET Core interfaces are usually in separate much slimmer •.Abstractions packages. You should reference  Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions instead of Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

Comment: Both `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http` and `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.Abstractions` are now marked as deprecated, so I would advise against using these. @Matthew referenced the correct solution, which is to add a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.App` framework reference to your `.csproj` file.

Comment: @exploring.cheerily.impresses Microsoft.AspNetCore.App is shown as both deprecated and vulnerable on nuget. It should not be used.

Comment: @Victor Zakharov the suggestion was to add a framework reference to Microsoft.AspNetCore.App, not a NuGet package. It involves adding a section to the .csproj file.